# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable because of y=int(x[2:4])

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to multiply a number of 6 digits and its 2 central digits, but in the loop where the calculation takes place an exception is thrown:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable because of the y=int(x[2:4])

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable because of the
y=int(x[2:4])
```

What can I do to correct this error?

```
x=input("Enter a numer of at least 6 digits: ")
while len(x)!=6:
    x=input("Enter a numer of at least 6 digits: ")

x1=int(x)
z=int(input("How many times do you want to repeat the procces? "))
r=range(z)

for i in r:
    y=int(x[2:4])
    x=y*x1
    print(x)
```

Comment: Are you trying to slice digits out of a number?

Comment: `x` is string on the first iteration of the loop. Once you set `x=y*x1`, x becomes an int. You have to reset it back into a string. One way you could do it is by doing `x = str(x)`.

Comment: You are interchangeably using `x` and `x1` one of them is `int` and the other `string`. And then you convert `x` to `int`

Comment: This is why people like static type checking. It would prevent you from changing your string to an int by refusing to compile.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can convert `x` into `str`, extract the middle digits, and then convert them back into `int`.

Modify your code as follows:

```py
for i in r:
    y=int(str(x)[2:4])
    x=y*x1
    print(x)
```

### Edit

As pointed out by @byxor, you should not change types of your variable `x`:

```py
for i in r:
    y = int(x[2:4])
    x = str(y*int(x))
    print(x)
```

### Side note

Although you want to get the middle 2 digits and multiply them with `x` for `z` times. Your number `x` might become more than 6 digits and you would not be selecting the middle 2 digits anymore. This solution fixes your the error at best.

Comment: This works fine and does the job, but be wary that changing the types of existing variables isn't a good practice

Comment: Thank you, as an answer to the side note, I didn't post it but one of the instructions was to select the middle 2 digits from the first 6 digits. Thank you, so much.

Comment: I'll talk to my teacher so he can tell me how to avoid changing the type fo the variables, thank you, @byxor